# Getting OSSpinLockLock when using Grand Central Dispatch (GCD)

Tags: ios, multithreading, cocoa-touch, thread-safety, grand-central-dispatch

We're using GCD to perform some image processing operations 'in the background' in our image editor view which works great.  The problem is if we open the editor view, do some processing and then just sit in the editor view for 10-20 minutes we get these `OSSpinLockLock` freezes, but we're not using `SpinLocks` or locks of any kind, we have these properties:

```
@property (nonatomic, readonly) dispatch_semaphore_t processingSemaphore;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) dispatch_queue_t serialQueue;
```

and setup the queues like so:

```
processingSemaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(1);
serialQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.myapp.imageProcessingQueue", NULL);
dispatch_set_target_queue(serialQueue, dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, NULL));
```

and process thusly:

```
dispatch_async(self.serialQueue, ^{
    dispatch_semaphore_wait(self.processingSemaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);

    ....<do stuff>....

    dispatch_semaphore_signal(self.processingSemaphore);

    dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        ....<notify that we're done>....
    }];
});
```

I'm wondering if its the semaphore somehow.

Answer (score 2):

libdispatch does not use OSSpinLockLock either in the queue or the semaphore implementation, but malloc does (and thus Block_copy, which libdispatch calls as part of dispatch_async).

Can you show the backtraces of all threads when you are blocked in OSSpinLockLock ?

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't help, the pertinent information is in the intermediate frames that are being hidden by Xcode. Probably easiest to just run `thread backtrace all` in lldb (the Xcode debugger console) instead.

Comment: Am I interpreting your response correctly that in copying any objects to the block (by referencing objects outside of the block) that this could be causing the problem?  ie within the block I reference an object outside the block that is also simultaneously  referenced on the main thread.

Comment: what I meant was that Block_copy() calls malloc() which uses OSSpinLockLock(). dispatch_async() needs to copy the block it is passed from the stack to the heap using Block_copy() so that it can be executed safely even after the calling stackframe has returned. What the block itself references does not matter for the purposes of the copying (other than influencing the size of the allocation). However there could be many other reasons besides malloc() why OSSpinLockLock is being called, which is why more information is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps instead of using the semaphore you could create a serial queue. Create your queue like this:

```
serialQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.myapp.imageProcessingQueue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);
```

This will ensure only one block at a time is executed.

You cannot cancel operations on this queue though. To do that you will need to use NSOperationQueue.

Comment: You're right, if I'm using a serial queue then I shouldn't need a semaphore.  Canceling is ok, I deal with that via a `_stopProcessing` boolean.